# Tokenize return letters instead of words

Tags: python

I try to tokenize my text following method in medium page below. After running the code, tokens returns are letters. Can you help to make it returns words instead? HHC

https://odsc.medium.com/using-text-features-to-predict-the-great-stock-market-crash-of-1929-ebffa5a02097

```
import pysentiment2 as ps
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

texts = 'why it return letter instead of words'

# Instantiate tokenizer for LM dictionary.
lm = ps.LM()
# Tokenize texts.
tokens = [lm.tokenize(t) for t in texts]
# Compute sentiment for each document.
sentiment = [lm.get_score(p)['Polarity'] for p in tokens]
print(sentiment)
tokens
```

Answer (score 0):

without looking too much to the code and test it, `texts` is probably supposed to be list of sentences, so try this instead:

```
texts = ['why it return letter instead of words']
```

Answer (score 0):

This corrected code will give you list of word as output:

```
    import pysentiment2 as ps

    # Text to analyze
    texts = 'why it returns letter instead of words'

    # Instantiate tokenizer for LM dictionary
    lm = ps.LM()

    # Tokenize the text into words
    tokens = lm.tokenize(texts)

    # Compute sentiment for the document
    sentiment = lm.get_score(tokens)['Polarity']

    # Print the sentiment score and tokens
    print("Sentiment Score:", sentiment)
    print("Tokens:", tokens)
```